# Virtuemart - disable all options of the checkout process, edit information gathered

Tags: joomla, field, checkout, virtuemart

I'm trying to disable all the options of the checkout process.  Also I need(due to this project I'm working on) to edit the information asked at checkout, to ask some specific questions my clients has to do in order to process the order.

Does anybody knows what are the php files That are needed to edit in order to get this done? In the Virtuemart admin option there are 2 checkout options that can't be disabled; why?  Does my joomla admin user doesn't have the access to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to disable payment and confirmation without hacking the core. Even if the user is not paying, like a purchase order or COD, the system still has to know how payment is going to be made. The confirmation page is the page that commits an order to the database, without it orders would never be completed.

As for the registration fields, you can manage those through the VM admin in the Admin menu click Manage User Fields.

Comment: I see.  Then, which should be the core files that manage this?  At least it could be possible to set up standard payment options through code, and just make that portion not visible to the user(the html i say).

Comment: Brent, you`re great; another thing: I've been trying to edit the text on the checkout page.  For example, changing the "checkout" word for something else.  So far I haven't found the php files that handle this.  Where should I look?

Comment: In general, you will want to make any edits in the theme files. It's good practice to leave the default theme unedited and make a renamed copy of the theme so you can always go back to it if something goes wrong. The files you are looking for are in JOOMLA/components/com_virtuemart/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates.